Excel Defined Names
I am usng Excel 2019 and wouldn't like to program anything with VBA.
What I have is a list of pre-defined formulas.
Examples:



NAME
FUNCTION




_1100
Function (Formula) 1


_1101
Function (Formula) 2


_1102
Function (Formula) 3


_1103
Function (Formula) 4



What I would like to do is to be able to retreive the corresponding function based on a cell value.
For example:
if in cell B2 we have value 1100, I want to use in cell C2 Function 1
if in cell B2 we have value 1102, I want to use in cell C2 Function 3
and so on...
How can I achieve that?
Thank you for your support.
